# Updating database without PK after DataGridView changes

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc

I've been stuck at this for a while now, so I hope someone can help me out on this one.

I have an Access database. It's an old one and I want to replace it by SQL Server asap, but for practical reason I need to work with this one for now. 
In my application, I have a datagridview. Here, I load data from the Access-database and the user can change it. All good so far.

Then I have a Save-button for the user to commit his changes. Normally, I would use this code for it:

```
//Data adapter initialized with a select-command when the gridview was filled.    
OdbcDataAdapter adapter;
OdbcCommandBuilder builder = new OdbcCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.Udpate(table);
```

However, now I get the error message `"Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key"`, which is because my database does not have a primary key (it contains multiple entries per ID thus can't be a valid PK).

So I thought I'd write my own Update-command:

```
OdbcCommand updateCommand = new OdbcCommand("UPDATE myTable SET name = ?,  mobile = ?, notes = ? WHERE id = ?", connection);
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = ???
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@mobile", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = ???
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@notes", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = ???;
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", OdbcType.Int).Value = ID_is_known;
adapter.UpdateCommand = updateCommand;
```

However, I don't know what to enter at the '???' of the parameters. Since it is a generalized update-command, I can't use the rows in the datagridview.

Can anybody help me in finishing the updateCommand? Or am I completely on the wrong path and is there a better/easier solution to this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there some combination of columns (fields) in the table that can serve as a Primary Key (i.e., uniquely identify each row)? If so, then create a PK on those columns and include all of those columns in the SelectCommand for the OdbcDataAdapter. If not, then can you add an AutoNumber field to the table and make it the PK?

Comment: Had some problems with the editing because of the old Access-version, but in the end this worked, thanks!